# How do I get the broadcast address of my wifi network using Swift?

Tags: swift, udp, multicast

currently I am using GCDAsyncUdpSocket to send a udp broadcast. Currently, the code sends it to a hardcoded 255.255.255.255 address. Is that the correct broadcast address on all networks? Will it fail on certain networks? What is the correct swift code?

```
socket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
socket!.send(ipRequestData!, toHost: "255.255.255.255", port: discoveryPort, withTimeout: 10000, tag: 0)
```

This question has an answer but it is in Objective-C
[Calculating the Broadcast Address in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077133/calculating-the-broadcast-address-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your broadcast address depends on your host address and the subnet mask. You can find the formula to calculate the broadcast address on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address):

```
broadcastAddress = ipAddress | ~subnetMask
```

You can calculate it with the following function:

```
func calculateBroadcastAddress(ipAddress: String, subnetMask: String) -> String {
    let ipAdressArray = ipAddress.split(separator: ".")
    let subnetMaskArray = subnetMask.split(separator: ".")
    guard ipAdressArray.count == 4 && subnetMaskArray.count == 4 else {
        return "255.255.255.255"
    }
    var broadcastAddressArray = [String]()
    for i in 0..<4 {
        let ipAddressByte = UInt8(ipAdressArray[i]) ?? 0
        let subnetMaskbyte = UInt8(subnetMaskArray[i]) ?? 0
        let broadcastAddressByte = ipAddressByte | ~subnetMaskbyte
        broadcastAddressArray.append(String(broadcastAddressByte))
    }
    return broadcastAddressArray.joined(separator: ".")
}
```

Example:

```
let broadcastAddress = calculateBroadcastAddress(ipAddress: "172.16.0.0", subnetMask: "255.240.0.0")
```

Result:

```
"172.31.255.255"
```

In general, you should never choose the `main` queue for network operations because it will lead to lags in the user interface (which is drawn in the main queue). Better use

```
let udpSocket = GCDAsyncUdpSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.global())
```

Do not forget to explicitly enable broadcasts for this socket

```
do {
    try udpSocket?.enableBroadcast(true)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Also consider that Apple enforces an iOS app to work with IPv6, which does not support broadcasts but [multicasts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast). So maybe you should switch to multicasts at least if your device is inside a pure IPv6 network.

Comment: Also. Does my code appear to be doing a multicast or a broadcast?

Comment: I added the Swift code to my answer. I do not understand your second question. You are sending to 255.255.255.255, which is definitely a broadcast address.

Comment: Will 255.255.255.255 work on all WiFi networks or will some networks require using a different address for broadcasts?

Comment: This depends on your network topology. Please really read the Wikipedia article to understand how broadcasts work.

Comment: thank you much. Getting ip address and subnet mask seem to be also some complicated code.

Comment: according to the wikipedia article 255 should send to the local network just fine it seems